# How cppwinrt.exe tool know which C++ version to use to generate the headers from .winmd files?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I don't see any switch to specify the "C++ version" in the cppwinrt.exe tool !

(my fundamental assumption is cppwinrt.exe tool binds the C++ 17 syntax to the ABI, I can't figure out how it can bind C++ 20 or future newer  versions syntax )

Similarly, the cswinrt.exe tool from C#/WinRT projection generates .cs files from .winmd files. The same question applies , How does the cswinrt.exe tool know which "C# version" to use to generate the .cs files ?

I don't see any switch to specify the "C# version" in the cswinrt.exe tool either !

end goal : is to understand how "language versions" fit in the WinRT language projections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [cppwinrt.exe](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/tree/master/cppwinrt) tool doesn't allow you to specify a C++ language standard. It simply defaults to C++17, with the ability to opt-in to newer language features by way of [feature test](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) macros.

The result is that the generated header files can be compiled with any C++17 compiler, or a compiler that supports a later language version.

At this time (C++/WinRT version 2.0.210922.5) there are four C++20 features in use:

- C++20 coroutines, guarded by an `#ifdef __cpp_lib_coroutine` directive (though that is really just deciding on whether to include the *coroutine* header file from the *experimental/* directory or not; coroutines have been supported since VS 2015).
- C++20 modules. This isn't guarded as clients need to explicitly opt-in to using *winrt.ixx* through an [`import`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/import) declaration.
- Support for C++20 ranges (introduced in [2.0.210329.4](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/releases/tag/2.0.210329.4)). This is an interesting one in that none of the code changes require a C++20 compiler. The feature simply lights up for clients using a C++20 compiler when they use the [*<ranges>*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ranges) standard library header.
- C++20 `std::format` (introduced in [2.0.210922.5](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/releases/tag/2.0.210922.5)), guarded by an `#ifdef __cpp_lib_format` directive.

At a fundamental level, C++/WinRT is just a C++ library. As such it can employ any technique that's suitable to providing language-adaptive implementations.

I don't know how C#/WinRT operates internally, nor C# for that matter, so I cannot comment on that.

Comment: so, cppwinrt.exe v2 is always based on c++17 no matter what , right? does the same applies to C#/WinRT where cswinrt.exe  v1.x is based on .NET 5 C# syntaxes no matter what, right ? BTW, I just saw Kenny Kerr issued C++/WinRT v3 targeting C++23 as min version. https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/1123

Comment: @TheUniverse As IInspectable said, C++/WinRT supports C++17 and higher, and the generated header files will take advantage of selected C++20 features if they detect that they are being used by a C++20 compiler. Since C++20 is largely backward compatible with C++17, the headers don't need separate C++17 and C++20 versions. They can just "light up" C++20 features selectively.

Comment: @RaymondChen. That's clearer. I get it now. Thanks

Comment: For the C# side, C# has the advantage that BCL features are separate from language version. So CsWinRT doesn't need to target a newer language version to use new BCL features. Newer language versions ends up amounting to more syntax sugar.

Comment: @cha I have reworked your proposed edit. Please have a look to see whether the information is accurate.

Comment: Yep, seems good to me @IInspectable